# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined - Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, javascript-objects

I'm confused about how to use, define, change and unset javascript object.

My javascript object is:

```
var Ship = function(){
    return {
        canvas: $('#area')[0],
        canvas_width: this.canvas.width,
        canvas_height: this.canvas.height,
        context: this.canvas.getContext("2d"),
        ship_image: new Image(),
        ship_width: null,
        ship_height: null,
        ship_x: 0,
        ship_y: 0,
        init: function() {
            this.ship_image.onload = function() {
                this.ship_width = this.width;
                this.ship_height = this.height;
                this.ship_x = (this.canvas_width / 2) - (this.ship_width / 2);
                this.ship_y = this.canvas_height - this.height;

                this.draw(
                    this.ship_x,
                    this.ship_y
                );
            }

            this.ship_image.src = "ship.gif";
        },
        draw: function(x, y) {
            this.context.drawImage(
                this.ship_image,
                x,
                y
            );
        }
    }
}();
```

When i execute this code like;

```
$(function(){
    Ship.init();
    Controller.init();
});
```

I get this error every time.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined on line 4 (ship.js)
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Ship is not a function on line 29
> (index.html / Ship.init())

What should i do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `this.canvas` doesn't point to the `canvas` property of the object `ship`, it points to global object `window`. You need to initialize `canvas_width` diferently, for example in init function. And the same thing with `context`:

```
var Ship = function () {
    return {
        canvas: $('#area')[0],
        ship_image: new Image(),
        ship_width: null,
        ship_height: null,
        ship_x: 0,
        ship_y: 0,
        init: function () {

            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            this.canvas_width = this.canvas.width;
            this.canvas_height = this.canvas.height;

            this.ship_image.onload = function () {
                this.ship_width = this.ship_image.width;
                this.ship_height = this.ship_image.height;
                this.ship_x = (this.canvas_width / 2) - (this.ship_width / 2);
                this.ship_y = this.canvas_height - this.ship_image.height;

                this.draw(this.ship_x, this.ship_y);
            }.bind(this);

            this.ship_image.src = "ship.gif";
        },
        draw: function (x, y) {
            this.context.drawImage(this.ship_image, x, y);
        }
    }
}();
```

Comment: `context: this.canvas.getContext("2d"),` this same :-)

Comment: How to reach draw function inside init? Because draw is; Uncaught TypeError: this.draw is not a function.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan Yes, indeed, there is one more problem with context. Check updated answer code. The thing is that inside `this.ship_image.onload` handler `this` points to image instance object. So you can simply bind this function to proper `this` and use `this.ship_image.width` instead of `this.width`.

Comment: Is it better to defined that context, canvas_width and canvas_height with default values and change that values in the init function?

Comment: Yes, you can define them first and then initialize in init, it's a matter of preference. `context: null, canvas_width: null`.